# two inputs into a while loop

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, conditional-statements

The basic idea of my code is for the user to enter either the spelling of 0-9 i.e. zero, one etc. or the actual numeral and for it to output the numeral/spelling respectively.

I managed to do this with a while loop using `while(cin >> number)` (number being a string variable) and then use if statements to select the appropriate output option i.e. "zero" --> 0, and "0"--> zero.

At first though I tried to do it as follows;

```
while (cin >> number || cin >> n) 
{
    if (n == 0)
        cout << digits[0] << endl;
           .
           . 
           .
    else if (n == 9)
        cout << digits[9] << endl;  

    if (number == digits[0])
        cout << 0 << endl;
           .
           .
           .
    else if (number == digits[9])
        cout << 9 << endl;  
}
```

`digits` is just a vector class that stores the strings "zero", "one" etc.

This didn't work though, when a string was entered the output was correct but when an integer was entered the output was always "zero". I was wondering why this doesn't work? I figured its something to do with the while loop conditions. Can't the computer identify if a string/integer was entered and carry out the appropriate action?

Comment: Why all the `if/else if`s? Why not just `cout<<digits[n]<<endl;`?

Comment: Yeh I can see how that would be a whole lot better but that would only work if the input was an integer. what if my input was a string?

Comment: Oh, well if it's a string, then you need to do `if (n == "0")` rather than `if (n == 0)`.

Comment: yeh your right, I think the red colour though implies "0", right?? I have changed the code now to only read in a string as suggested by the other users.

Comment: what color your numbers/strings are depends entirely on what software you're using and how it's configured. I have no idea what the red color implies in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cin >> number` is always going to succeed since `number` is a `string` (as long as you don't hit EOF or some other failure condition); if the user types in a digit, `number` is going to hold the number as a string. So `cin >> n` won't happen.

You should compare your `number` against the strings `"0"`..`"9"` instead (in addition to testing the digit names). You should also use a loop instead of a chain of `if/else if`.

Comment: Ok, I understand what's going on, thanks. I'll try modifying it with a loop.

Comment: I managed to construct a simple for loop for when the inputs are "zero", "one" etc. but I don't quite understand how I would use a loop for when the inputs are the strings "0", "1" etc. I appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you  understand the usage of the `||` operator. `while (cin >> number || cin >> n)` means do `cin >> number` and if that expression evaluates `false`, then do `cin >> n`, and if either one evaluates `true`, then do what's inside the brackets.

As nneonneo said, `cin >> number` will (almost) always evaluate `true`, so `cin >> n` will never happen, but that's actually the least of your problems.

If I might suggest, I think you ought to get rid of the `while` loop entirely for now, and just focus on doing it once. What you need is to `cin >> number` and then do a *test* on weather or not `number` is a `"0"`,`"1"`,...`"9"` number, or a `"zero"`,`"one"`,...`"nine"` number. Then you can decide on how to convert one to the other.

Comment: Going by what you said, I tried to see what `while (cin >> n || cin >> number)` would do. Shouldn't this do `cin >> n` and if false then do `cin >> number`. So if I enter the string `0` it should recognise it as an integer and store it as `n` but if `"zero"` was inputted as a string in `number`?